# facebook leadgen_id overflow issue in 32bit php

Tags: php, facebook, overflow, facebook-php-sdk, webhooks

I am working on a Facebook Leads webhook, which is written in PHP on IIS. And due to the environment limitations, `PHP_INT_SIZE` is only 4, and that isn't enough to handle `leadgen_id`, which is much larger than 2147483647, and the webhook will convert the integer to a float number, e.g. `1037822916323543` will become `1.0378229163235E+15`, and that's not a valid id.

So, what I can go to get the valid id from the webhook, so that I can use it to get the lead data?

Comment: Parse the JSON using the flag that makes big integers into strings.

Comment: It works. Thanks.